# JNI bindings : JVM can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, c, makefile, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create JNI bindings for a C project named shoco.
When trying to load the library with

```
System.loadLibrary("shocolibjni")
```

The JVM exits with error "JVM can't find dependent libraries".
I created a def file with the functions to export :

```
EXPORTS
shoco_compress
shoco_decompress
Java_org_shoco_Shoco_compress
Java_org_shoco_Shoco_decompress
```

I'm compiling using the updated makefile of the project  under MINGW64. 
I've tried to put the library into the system directory and to set the java.library.path to "."  but I'm getting the same error. I think there is no such thing as dependent libraries in this project.
What could be the issue?

JAVA code :

```
package org.shoco;

public class Shoco {

    static {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary("shocolibjni");
    }

    public static native String compress(String s);

    public static native String decompress(String s, int compressedLength);

    public static String decompress(String s) {
        return decompress(s, s.length());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "This is a string which is used for test";
        String c = compress(s);
        System.out.println(c);
        String d = decompress(c);
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Header file org_shoco_Shoco.h :

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#define __int64 int64_t
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class org_shoco_Shoco */
#ifndef _Included_org_shoco_Shoco
#define _Included_org_shoco_Shoco
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     org_shoco_Shoco
 * Method:    compress
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_shoco_Shoco_compress
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);

/*
 * Class:     org_shoco_Shoco
 * Method:    decompress
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_shoco_Shoco_decompress
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

C file org_shoco_Shoco.c :

```
#define __int64 int64_t
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "org_shoco_Shoco.h"


/*
 * Class:     org_shoco_Shoco
 * Method:    compress
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_shoco_Shoco_compress
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass jcl, jstring jstr)
{
    char buffer[4096];
    const char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jstr, 0);
    shoco_compress(str, 0, buffer, 4096);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstr, str);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buffer);
}

/*
 * Class:     org_shoco_Shoco
 * Method:    decompress
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_shoco_Shoco_decompress
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass jcl, jstring jstr, jint comp_len)
{
    char buffer[4096];
    const char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jstr, 0);
    shoco_decompress(str, comp_len, buffer, 4096);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstr, str);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buffer);

}
```

Makefile :

```
FLAGS=$(CFLAGS) -std=c99 -O3 -Wall -I"/c/jdk1.7.0_80/include" -I"/c/jdk1.7.0_80/include/win32"
SOURCES=shoco.c org_shoco_Shoco.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
HEADERS=shoco.h shoco_model.h org_shoco_Shoco.h
GENERATOR=generate_compressor_model.py
TRAINING_DATA_DIR=training_data
TRAINING_DATA=$(wildcard training_data/*.txt)
TABLES_DIR=models
TABLES=$(TABLES_DIR)/text_en.h $(TABLES_DIR)/words_en.h $(TABLES_DIR)/filepaths.h

.PHONY: all
all: shoco shocolibjni.dll

shoco: shoco-bin.o $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -s $< -o $@

test_input: test_input.o $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -s $< -o $@

$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< -c

shoco_model.h: $(TABLES_DIR)/words_en.h
    cp $< $@

.PHONY: models
models: $(TABLES)

$(TABLES_DIR)/text_en.h: $(TRAINING_DATA) $(GENERATOR)
    python $(GENERATOR) $(TRAINING_DATA) -o $@

$(TABLES_DIR)/words_en.h: $(TRAINING_DATA) $(GENERATOR)
    python $(GENERATOR) --split=whitespace --strip=punctuation $(TRAINING_DATA) -o $@

$(TABLES_DIR)/dictionary.h: /usr/share/dict/words $(GENERATOR)
    python $(GENERATOR) $< -o $@

# Warning: This is *slow*! Use pypy when possible
$(TABLES_DIR)/filepaths.h: $(GENERATOR)
    find / -print 2>/dev/null | pypy $(GENERATOR) --optimize-encoding -o $@

.PHONY: check
check: tests

tests: tests.o $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $< -o $@
    ./tests

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.o

.PHONY: js
js: shoco.js

shoco.js: $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS) pre.js
    emcc shoco.c -O3 -o $@ --closure 1 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_shoco_compress', '_shoco_decompress']" --pre-js pre.js

shocolibjni.dll: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared $^ -o $@ org_shoco_Shoco.def
```

Comment: Is the dll/so on the `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`,  or in a folder in the Java system property `java.library.path`? Please show more code, and describe where this library is located relative to your Java application?

Comment: Questions should be self contained.

Comment: More code posted.

Comment: Check with Dependency Walker what the dependent libraries are and if they're on the PATH. `java.library.path` is not enough because Windows doesn't know about that. If you cannot modify PATH you can alternatively explicitly load the dependent libraries with their fully qualified name before loading the JNI library.